# Is the compiler Xcode uses to produce Assembly code a bad compiler?

Tags: c, xcode, assembly, compiler-construction

I generated a new Xcode project in C and immediately looked at the assembly that it produces.

Here is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The assembly code is almost 400 lines. This seems like a bit much...
Can someone explain why this is?
Also what compiler does it use anyways?

Comment: Did you look to see what the assembly code is? Is it mostly static declarations and directives, or is it mostly machine instructions?

Comment: I have only ever used mips, but it looks like there is only about 20 lines of machine instructions including a call to _printf which I assume is object code for the printf method in c. So why does it need all this other declaration stuff?

Comment: Did you compile with debugging enabled?

Comment: Probably, it was produced by Xcode, you can set breakpoints during runtime so I would assume it must be compiled with debugging enabled

Comment: If your definition of "good compiler" is "produces a minimal text disassembly when compiled with debug and no optimization", then yes, clang is a terrible compiler.  However, that notion of "good" isn't really shared by anyone else in the world.

Comment: I am looking for answers that explain why so much assembly code is produced whether it be due to the debugger or duplicate code etc. I was not implying any notion of what a good compiler is.